# Does anyone know the default mark size for a circle in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to use the `mark size` option relative to the current default size of a circle mark.  Page 130 of the pgfplots manual mentions that the dimension for a circle is the radius, but does not mention what it is.  Does anyone know off the top of their head?  Adding "default" to my search turns up so many hits that I'm looking for a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good point. I will add documentation for the initial value. It is set to `2pt` (taken from the tikz source code).